# Is word "homological" homologous?

Tags: terminology

Homological mean the word describing itself (like "word" or "written"). Is word "homological" homological?
Thank you very much and sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: This compound sentence is true, but this clause isn't. This is another version of Russell's Barber Paradox. Reflexives are not good to have in definitions; recursion leads to infinities.

Comment: Who shaves the barber?

Comment: [Qui custodiet ipsos custodes?](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=sK8EVKPhDuSq8wfM64DYBQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=qui+custodiet+ipsos+custodes). Or [Can Jesus warm up a burrito so hot that even He cannot eat it?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iz2qm_jsMAg)

Comment: It has long been known to philosophers that self-referential systems are paradoxical.

Answer (score 1):

In Greek, "homo" means same, as in 'of the same kind'. So a person who is attracted to a person of the same gender is *homosexual*. "Auto" on the other hand means "oneself". An "autograph" is something the person has written with his or her very own hand. Since this word is referring to itself, and not just to other words like it, it would seem to make more sense to describe words which predicate the properties they ascribe to themselves *autological* rather than *homological*. Wikipedia seems to agree: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/autological

Comment: Okay, but you didn't actually answer this question.

Comment: Yes homological is homological.

Answer (score 1):

As opposed to the comments, I see no paradox here.

Consider two situations:

- If the word is homological it means "a word that describes itself". This is definitely correct, but to exclude possible contradictions we have to think of the other possibility:
- The word is heterological. In this case "a word that describes itself" doesn't describe itself. This is not true.

But note that whether a word is homological (autological) totally depends on how it is defined (and how it is being used).

Originally, the concept of a "homological" word was invented because of a different dilema: if the word heterological (the opposite of *homological*) is a homological word.

This is a [true paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grelling%E2%80%93Nelson_paradox). It demonstates that we can't define a set such as the set of all sets, similiarly to the Rusell's paradox. This is was taken into account when defying the basic axioms, rules of logic in his book [*Principia Mathematica*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophi%C3%A6_Naturalis_Principia_Mathematica).

Comment: +1 for adding a reference to the Grelling-Nelson paradox.

Answer (score 0):

(I've gone back and forth on this answer, and have definitively determined: *it depends.*)

One definition of [homological](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/homological) is: "(grammar) Of an adjective, describing itself."

Based on this definition, *homological* is itself homological.

[Gödel, Escher, Bach](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0465026567), by Douglas R. Hofstadter, has a section devoted to "self-describing" and "non-self-describing" words. Putting all adjectives into two columns, he places "self-describing" in the "self-describing" column and most adjectives (like "blue" or "noisy") in the "non-self-describing" column. But the fun begins when he tries to place "non-self-describing" in a column.

One should place "homological" in the self-describing column if using the grammatical definition.

However, if one is using it in the biology sense: "Having a similar evolutionary origin; homologous," it should go in the non-self-describing column. It has no biological properties. Based on the biological definition, *homological* is not homological.

And a tip of the hat to [Russell's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox) and to its semantic exception, the [Grelling-Nelson paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grelling%E2%80%93Nelson_paradox).